# NoMethodError on Ruby program

Tags: ruby

I'm VERY new to Ruby, so please forgive me. 
I created a method funny_sort that sorts an array naturally and then returns the new array,

```
def funny_sort(the_array)
    the_array = new_array.each {|s| s.gsub /\D/, ""}
    the_array = new_string.each{|s| s.to_i}
    the_array = new_string.sort_by{|s| s.gsub /\D/, ""}
    return the_array
end

    w = ['app100le', 'car10rot', 'banana']
puts w.funny_sort
```

but when I run the program in Command prompt with Ruby and Rails, I get the following error:

```
sort.rb:10in '<main>': private method 'funny_sort' called for ["app1001e", "carrot10", "banana"]:Array <NoMethodError>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call it *on* an array, instead of *passing* it the array.

```
funny_sort w  # Or with parens...
funny_sort(w)
```

You may have another issue with that `new_array` and `new_string` in there, though, and I suspect that `.each` does not return what you believe it does.